# Is there a way to manipulate udp packets after an application sends it to a socket?

Tags: sockets, udp

In other words, can I intercept those packets (possibly at the stack level) using a separate application, manipulate them and then send them to the destination the original application was trying to send them to?

Answer (score 2):

You can open socket with PF_PACKET protocol type, intercept all packets on the interface and send them directly.

Check out `man 7 packet` and `man socket`. I believe you'll need root rights to run such application.

[Sniffing Bytes over the Network](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4659)